# Inverse of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, inverse-function

Suppose that a holomorphic function $f$ from a regon $G$ to another region $H$ has a right inverse and this $f$ is locally bijective (that is the derivative of $f$ does not vanish).

Then is it true that this right inverse of $f$ is actually the 2-sided inverse (simply the inverse function) of $f$? I think it is true...but somewhat confused.

Comment: Might there not be regions in the complex plane where $e^z$ is not injective, but still a continuous branch of $log z$ may be defined on the image region?  Is that the sort of thing you ask about?

Comment: That is right. Is it possible?

Comment: Does "region" mean "connected open set" (more commonly called a domain), or just an arbitrary open set? (Pretty sure it's the former because for the latter it's easy to find counterexamples.)

Comment: I interpret your question as "Suppose $G,H$ are connected open sets and $f:G\to H,$ $g:H\to G$ are both holomorphic. If $f\circ g(z) = z$ on $H,$ is it true that $g\circ f(z) = z$ on $G?$" Is this what you mean?

Comment: @zhw  yes and there must be another condition that f is localy bijective

Comment: I don't think we need to assume local bijectivity of $f.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $G,H$ are connected open sets and $f:G\to H, g:H\to G$ are holomorphic. If $f\circ g(z) = z$ on $H,$ then $g\circ f(z) = z$ on $H.$

Proof: For any $z\in H,$ $(g\circ f)(g(z)) = g(f\circ g(z)) = g(z)$ for all $z\in H.$ Another way to say that is $g\circ f (w) = w$ for all $w\in g(H).$ But $g$ is clearly non constant, so $g(H)$ is a nonempty open subset of $G$ by the open mapping theorem. By the identity principle, $g\circ f (w) = w$ everywhere in $G,$ and we're done.

Comment: Second sentence last $H$ should be $G$. I submitted an edit which was rejected: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1402170